# How to reset the encryptor password?

Tags: full-disk-encryption

So basically I have noticed that the keyboard layout was not set up correctly, and this possibly happened before I have set up the encryptor. I don't want to turn off the computer until I find a way to make it sure that the password was written correctly, I don't want to get locked out (even though I could eventually guess the password, because max two characters were swapped, but idk how many guesses the encryptor gives me).

Or is there a way to like disable this completely? That would be the best because I though this is the same as a user account, and thats the onl reason I have set it up

Answer (score 1):

There is a CLI Way of doing it but, I recommend the GUI Way as it is easier and prevents human error.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install GNOME Disks (Preinstalled in ubuntu but not on elmentary) by executing `sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility` in the terminal
   [image: GNOME Disks Install]
2. Open `Disks` from the Applications Menu and selected the LVM2 Partition (Highlighted Below)
   [image: GNOME D1]
3. Click the small settings-gear icon and click `change passphrase` to change your encryption password
   [image: GNOME D2]
4. Completed

P.S. `Change Passphrase` is disabled in the below screenshot as my drive is unencrypted.